# To check touch id disabled or not in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, fingerprint

I am trying to implement the Touch ID feature in iOS. I want to check whether the touchId has disabled or not, though device has fingerprint enrolled.

Comment: Have you used `LAContext canEvaluatePolicy`? Does it not do what you want?

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556384/how-to-check-touchid-enable-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You can take idea from below code for Touch Id and Face Id.

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;

NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"for Touch Id";
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    if (myContext.biometryType == LABiometryTypeFaceID) {
        myLocalizedReasonString = @"for Face Id";
    }
}

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            // Successfully recognized
        } else {
            // Failed to recognized
        }
    }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"%@",authError.localizedDescription);
    // Biometry not available/disable etc.
}
```